# Robocopy | copy only the newest pair of files

Tags: windows, batch-file, robocopy

I've been trying writing a script that will copy a pair of files. They're pretty much the same file: one in `.xlsx` and another in `.pdf`. Being financial reports, a pair of them is created whenever it needs to be created (not to say randomly). And there are many pairs for every project folder.

**I want to**

- Copy only the files that begin with `"financial"` - since that's a pattern between them;
- Always a pair: a `.xlsx` and a `.pdf` file;
- I need to copy only the `newest` pair.

```
@CHCP 65001
@echo off
robocopy "C:\source" "C:\dest" financial* (.xlsx*.pdf*) /XO /E /R:3
pause
```

The code I wrote above helped me. But it didn't fit my **third condition**, which is to copy only the newest pair. Does anybody know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```powershell
@echo off & >nul chcp 65001

2>nul cd/d "C:\Source\" && set "_destiny=\\to\target\folder\." || (
      timeout /t -1 | echo\Path do not exist: C:\Source && goto :eOf ) 

for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('dir/b/a-d/o-d/tc .\financial*.*^|findstr/lei "\.pdf \.xlsx"'
      )do 2>nul robocopy .\. "%_destiny%" "%%~ni.xlsx" "%%~ni.pdf" /mov /njh|find "100%%"
```

---

**1.** Go to the source folder, source of the files, suppress any possible error (`2>nul`):

```powershell
2>nul cd/d "C:\Source\."
```

**2.** If the folder exist, define your target, if it does not exist (if the bat is executed in the wrong location/work station), interrupt and alert your user..

```powershell
2>nul cd/d    ...    && set "_destiny=\\to\target\folder\." || (
 timeout -1 | echo\Path do not exist: C:\Source && goto :eOf )
```

**3.** List your files in order to get the most recent ones in your folder, and redirect that listing to `Findstr` to literally filter you for files ending in the desired extensions.

```powershell
dir/b/a-d/o-d/tc .\financial*.*^|findstr/lei "\.pdf \.xlsx"
```

**4.** Inform/pass the result of the looped command to `robocopy` (only the file name) but already limiting to copy (moving) both extensions, also the current folder (`.\.`) of source, and the target (`%_destiny%`).

```powershell
robocopy .\. "%_destiny%" "%%~ni.xlsx" "%%~ni.pdf" /mov /njh
```

**5.** Just a suggestion to limit the output, take the result per line where it appears 100%, redirecting the `robocopy` output to the `find`.

```powershell
robocopy    ...     |find "100%%"
```

---

**Obs.: 1.** You can also use the name of the current file in a loop in a previous verification of the condition to exist or not in pairs, using a `dir financial*.xlsx financial*.pdf`... only if there are both, the `&&` operator (means `return 0`) will execute the your `robocopy` command:

- ```powershell
  @echo off 
   
  2>nul cd/d "C:\Source\." && set "_destiny=\\to\target\folder\." || (
       timeout -1 | echo\Path do not exist: C:\Source && goto :eOf )
   
  1>nul chcp 65001 && set "_cmd=dir/b/a-d/o-d/tc .\"financial*.*""
   
  for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('%_cmd%^|findstr/lei "\.pdf \.xlsx"')do 2>nul dir /b .\"%%~ni.xlsx" .\"%%~ni.pdf" && (
       2>nul robocopy .\. "%_destiny%" "%%~ni.xlsx" "%%~ni.pdf" /mov /njh|find "100%%")
  ```

**Obs.: 2.** If the objective is to move a pair, not pairs, just add `& goto: eof`, causing the batch/loop to end/abort immediately.

- ```powershell
  @echo off 
   
  2>nul cd/d "C:\Source\" && set "_destiny=\\to\target\folder\." || (
     timeout -1 | echo\Path do not exist: C:\Source && goto :eOf )
   
  1>nul chcp 65001 && set "_cmd=dir/b/a-d/o-d/tc .\"financial*.*""
   
  for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('%_cmd%^|findstr/lei "\.pdf \.xlsx"')do 2>nul dir /b .\"%%~ni.xlsx" .\"%%~ni.pdf" && (
      2>nul robocopy .\. "%_destiny%" "%%~ni.xlsx" "%%~ni.pdf" /mov /njh|find "100%%" & goto :eOf)
  ```

**Obs.: 3.** If for some reason it is necessary to `move` files, some of which already exist in the destination folder, then you will need to overwrite it, then use/add **`/IS`** in your **`robocopy`** command.
It is

- ```powershell
  @echo off 
    
   1>nul chcp 65001 & set "_cmd=dir /b/a:-d/o:-d/t:c ".\financial*.*""
   2>nul cd /d "C:\Source\." && set "_target=\\to\target\folder\." || (
   timeout /t -1 | echo\Path/Source do not exist: C:\Source & goto :eOf)
    
   for /f tokens^=* %%i in ('2^>nul %_cmd% ^|findstr/lei "\.pdf \.xlsx"')do 2>nul (
   2>nul robocopy .\. "%_target%" "%%~ni.xlsx" "%%~ni.pdf" /mov /njh /is|find "100%%")
  ```